# Ant desgin create modal in a certain context (dont grey out the entire screen)

Tags: antd

Im using ant design 3.9*
When using Modal, by default the entire screen is greyed out. but I want only a certain component / html element to be greyed.

Half of the screen still needs to be available and part of the screen should be blocked by the Modal...

https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-torvalds-rsdyr?file=/index.js

```
 <div>
        <Button type="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>
          Open Modal
        </Button>
        <div
          style={{ width: "100%", height: "500px", border: "solid 1px red" }}
        >
          Modal container, I want to grey out this box
          <Modal
            title="Basic Modal"
            visible={this.state.visible}
            onOk={this.handleOk}
            onCancel={this.handleCancel}
          >
            <p>Some contents...</p>
            <p>Some contents...</p>
            <p>Some contents...</p>
          </Modal>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58398456/show-antd-modal-mask-in-some-div

Comment: @FatemehQasemkhani thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [show antd modal mask in some div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58398456/show-antd-modal-mask-in-some-div)